# SQL INSERT with select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables t1 and t2 basically, t1 contains code 3299 against ind_ref 86034 where t2 is missing that code. 
I want to do an insert in t2 and get the code 3299 from t1 .

here is t1

```
IND_REF Code
86034   3299
```

here is t2

```
IND_REF Code
86034   1212
```

I want to see the output as

```
IND_REF Code
86034   1212
86034   3299 <-- as insert from t1
```

How can i achieve this,

Here is my query, but it doesnt update.

```
INSERT INTO test.DBO.ATTRIBUTE (ATTR_CODE_REF)


select ((SELECT att.ATTR_CODE_REF 
                                FROM individual ind
                                join contact c on c.individual_ref=ind.individual_ref
                                join organisation org on org.organisation_Ref=c.ORGANISATION_REF and c.main_organisation='y' and c.valid_to is null  --contact_ref
                                join attribute att on att.organisation_ref=org.organisation_ref and att.code_type=3299
                             where iND.individual_ref=86034))--@indref) 
                              from ATTRIBUTE                                                        
            WHERE ATTRIBUTE.INDIVIDUAL_REF=86034
```

Comment: So, can you describe more detail in your current table structure and also paste some sample data and your expect output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `insert into .... select` with `NOT exists`.

insert into data in `t2`, which missing `Code` from `t1`.

```
insert into t2 (IND_REF,Code) 
SELECT IND_REF,Code 
FROM t1 
WHERE NOT exists
(
    SELECT IND_REF,Code
    FROM t2
    where t1.Code = t2.Code
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=111455733251ef0ff19b9571e7fb1eae)

Answer (score 1):

Use Union All Operator to vertically combine two tables of same no of columns:

```
SELECT [IND_REF],[CODE] FROM t1 WHERE [IND_REF]=86034
UNION ALL
SELECT [IND_REF],[CODE] FROM t2 WHERE [IND_REF]=86034
```

Answer (score 1):

--You can use insert based on select

```
INSERT INTO t2 (IND_REF ,Code)
SELECT IND_REF ,Code
FROM t2 
WHERE IND_REF = 86034
```